# Column name already belongs to this DataTable error in C#

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get passed this error message using this code.

`System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named 'Url' already belongs to this DataTable.`

```
foreach (var user in users.Users)
{
      using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
      {
         table.Clear();
         for (int i = 0; i < users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties().Count(); i++)
         {
            table.Columns.Add(users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties()[i].Name);
            Console.WriteLine(table.Columns.Add(users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties()[i].Name));
         }
      }

}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

```
var properties = users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties();    

for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count(); i++) 
{
    table.Columns.Add(properties[i].Name, typeof(String));
}
```

Because I didn't know what the type was to use the foreach.  This:

```
var properties = users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInformation prop in properties)
{
     table.Columns.Add(properties.);
     Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
}
```

gave me `Cannot convert type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' to 'System.Configuration.PropertyInformation'`

Anyway I can figure out how to get the correct type in there? @barrick

Comment: First, take `users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties()` outside the loop and into a variable. That's besides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error won't lie. In the `Console.WriteLine()` call, you're adding the column again, which will cause the problem.

Try:

```
var properties = users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
{
    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
}
```

Comment: I did properties.GetType(); and it says it's an array.  But when I substitute PropertyInfo for an Array it Visual Studio errors out.

Comment: The correct type is `PropertyInfo` as in the original answer, and as in the [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties(v=vs.110).aspx]). If you're having problems with that, then you'll need to add a reference to `System.Reflection`, and then add a `using` statement at the top of the class.